# pandas column didn't change permanently

Tags: pandas

This is my code having trouble. In double for loop, I created a temporary data frame which will be added into the original data frame. Before I add, I changed columns. But the column didn't change when I checked final data frame.

```
df['sd'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df['sd'])

copy_columns_of_x = ['consumer_price_index', 'households', 'income', 'avg_price_jeonse', 'total_unsold_households_rate']
copy_columns_of_y = ['avg_price_meme']
df[copy_columns_of_x] = standard_scaler.fit_transform(df[copy_columns_of_x])

df_orgin = df.copy()
columns = copy_columns_of_x

for c in copy_columns_of_x:
    for h in HISTORY_FRAME_TO_PREDICT:    
        tmp_df = df_orgin.sort_values(['sd','yyyymmdd']).groupby(['sd'])[c].transform(lambda x:x.shift(h))
        changed_column = c + '_' + str(h)         # todo : 이거 왜 안먹지?
        tmp_df.columns = [changed_column]
        df = pd.concat([df, tmp_df], axis=1)
```

Comment: add some data to replicate

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `inplace=True` in your code `df = pd.concat([df, tmp_df], axis=1)`

Comment: pd.concat function doesn't have it. Instead I set df get return value.